# Mylyn removed from Eclipse 2022-06 -- workarounds?

Tags: eclipse

Mylyn is/was an important productivity feature, and among others, a reason that made me stick to Eclipse for some projects -- especially with large code base. In a nutshell, you get direct integration with Bugtracking/Workflow software, and for each issue there is a filtered context, and thus the relevant parts / files / classes / artefacts are immediately in sight when working on a topic, and you can switch context/topic anytime easily.

Thus I'm shocked that Mylyn seemingly was **removed from the coordinated Eclipse releases**. If I understand correct, there were dependency issues related to `javax.xml.bind` vs. `jakarta.xml.bind` and similar stuff; these were known since 2020, and not enough developer power available to come up with a sustainable solution; the log4j exploit mandated upgrades, and the existing workarounds caused follow-up problems, so in the end, Mylyn was removed from the coordinated release trains starting with 2022-06

### Questions

- any known workarounds? and how to apply them?
- any other known OpenSource solutions that allow you to keep track of several contexts within a huge code base, and switch between them similar to Eclipse Mylyn?
- any known workarounds how at least to get hierarchical bugs/issues/topics into the IDE and maybe associate bookmarks? So you won't have to jump through gazillions of clunky web interfaces like an idiot?

### References

- [Heads-up on the issue 2021-05](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg18358.html)
- [Decision to remove Mylyn](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg18881.html)
- [Planning Council Decision:remove with 2022-06](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg18974.html)

Comment: Bad news indeed though I don't fully understand since Mylyn is working on my 20220609-1112 eclipse.

Comment: Since Task List is actually broken by a dependency constraint violation, it might still be possible maybe to keep it running with very specific versions. However, likely this will break sooner or later, since more other plugins are migrating to `jakarta.xml.bind` (as everyone should)

Comment: Downloading zips and using with an old eclipse is a workaround I think. https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/drops/

Comment: Become a Mylyn contributer/committer.

Comment: where is the documentation how to do that, and would be one afternoon every two months be enough to make an impact? </sarcasm>

Comment: Your sarcasm is uncalled for. Open source projects like Eclipse depend on volunteers to keep projects going, if you aren't willing to volunteer you can't really complain when a project dies through lack of people. See [Contributing](https://www.eclipse.org/contribute/) if you really want to help.

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Contributor_Reference

Comment: As an active OpenSource developer, I could easily spend double my lifetime with helping abandoned projects. Thus my sarcasm.

And yes, if it was just search-and-replace javax for jakarta, the problem wouldn't be there. I have read the mail threads. For starters, it looks like there is no one left in charge, who could even coordinate the actions or decide what is to do to resolve some long standing problems (which I don't even remotely understand, without investing some weeks of learning the innards of the eclipse ecosystem)

Comment: I'm using 2022-06, and I have the task list, and I can create local tasks and "focus" on them in the Project Explorer (package explorer seems to have lost this), and I can switch back and forth between tasks. If Mylyn has been removed in 2022-06, I don't know what that means.

Comment: Well, it worked in July, but stopped working somewhere in August, and prevented some Eclipse updates to be installed. Thus, there is a lurking problem

Comment: Eclipse releases have been in June and September, not in July or August. There is a group of people who want to fix such Mylyn issues, see: https://www.eclipse.org/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/2022/Sep/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Recent post on mylyn-dev:

> Hello All,
>
> Mylyn 3.26.0 is ready.
>
> Please use its stable location
> https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/3.26/ instead of shifting
> https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/stage/latest/ SimRel contribution
> has been updated accordingly.
>
> Since this is the first release after project relaunch, we plan to
> produce another service release shortly in order to be in better shape
> for the upcoming 2023-06.
>
> Regards, AF

I took it for a quick spin on 2022-12 and it appears to work. I couldn't get the git commit message to auto-populate based on the active task but might be a configuration error, and it has always been a bit flaky for me anyway.

Kudos to the Mylyn team for bringing back such a useful feature! There was another post indicating that Mylyn will be a part of simultaneous release as well.

Answer (score 1):

Mylyn is back starting from Eclipse SimRel 2023-06, the most recent updates can be found here https://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/updates/